# how to get the selected value from codeigniter's default dropdown using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

I have a form and I am trying to submit data into database using Jquery-AJAX. I am using Codeigniter and I have a drop down select in my form.

Here's my dropdown

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('teacher', $dropdown_teacher,'', 'class="medium required"' ); ?>
```

Since the above drop down doesn't have any id, I cannot fetch the selected value using jquery. I have tried using `'id="teacher"'` after `'class="medium required"'` but it doesn't work. I have also tried to remove the `NULL` but still no result.

To get the value I tried this-

```
var teacher= $("#teacher").val();
```

Would you please kindly help me find out how to get the selected value from codeigniter's default dropdown jquery?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You need to show us the generated HTML. Have you tried `$('select[name="teacher"]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this :

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('teacher', $dropdown_teacher,'', 'class="medium required" id="teacher"' ); ?>
```

i think your var `teacher= $("#teacher").val();` will be working